# How to play .h264(Ex:globalwarming.h264) video file through cross browser for Web Application

Tags: javascript, angular, web, video-streaming

I have a video file with .h264 format, alternatively, tried VLC Media Player Plugin that can be hosted only in IE and not in any other browser but unable to find a solution for cross browser compatibility.

```
 <object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" 
 codebase="http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/last/win32/axvlc.cab" id="vlc">
    <param name="Src" value="http://globalwarming.h264" />
    <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" name="vlc" id="embedtag" 
    width="1

    000" height="1000" target="http://globalwarming.h264"  />
     </object>
```

How can I make the video compatible so it works over cross browsers(Chrome,Firefox,IE)?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not play raw h264 files. They must be in an mp4 container.

`ffmpeg -I globalwarming.h264 -codec copy globalwarming.mp4`